# Center view on horizontal middle of linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a layout xml to fit like the layout below:
[image: row_view_android]

This layout goes in a row of listview.
The problem is: The thumbnail need to fit the middle of the row horizontally, and the star too, this is my layout xml with best approach:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/favoriteVendor"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NameNameNameNameNameNameName"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:id="@+id/vendorName"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        <RatingBar
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pin_point_rating"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NameNameNameNameNaNameNameNameNameNameNameNamemeNameName"
                android:id="@+id/vendorAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/favoriteVendor"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:background="@drawable/star"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to do it? I've tried lot of combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a much better way to do this (This is just a layout, use padding as you wish)

```
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"/>

    <RatingBar
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pin_point_rating"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"/>


</LinearLayout>

<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/tb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem,i have using LinearLayout to achieved your requirement.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NameNameNameNameNameNameName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:id="@+id/vendorName"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
        <RatingBar
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pin_point_rating"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NameNameNameNameNaNameNameNameNameNameNameNamemeNameName"
            android:id="@+id/vendorAddress"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/favoriteVendor"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/star"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```